# How to correctly cache images

Tags: image, optimization, caching, image-caching

I just installed Google's Page Speed plugin to Firebug, and everything looks good except for caching.  I have set headers to cache my JS and CSS files, but it says the images aren't being cached.  How can I make sure the images get cached for 30 days?  These are static images, so I can't just add the headers with PHP like I did with the other files.

Comment: which webserver are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page at http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-cache-control.html suggests something like this:

> #### Add Cache-Control Headers
>
> This goes in your root .htaccess file but if you have access to httpd.conf that is better.
>
> This code uses the FilesMatch directive and the Header directive to add Cache-Control Headers to certain files.
>
> `# 480 weeks`
>      `<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">`
>      `Header set Cache-Control "max-age=290304000, public"`
>      `</FilesMatch>`

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but this is causing httpd to fail.  I added that into httpd.conf and then restarted httpd, but it won't restart unless I remove that from httpd.conf.

Comment: Nothing shows in the error log, and all it said when I tried restarting was "httpd has failed, please contact the sysadmin"

Answer (score -1):

Put the following caching header:

Cache-Control: max-age=2592000